# Island perimeter code challenge in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

Problem:

> Source (with example): https://leetcode.com/problems/island-perimeter/
>
> You are given a map in form of a two-dimensional integer grid where 1
>   represents land and 0 represents water.
>
> Grid cells are connected horizontally/vertically (not diagonally). The
>   grid is completely surrounded by water, and there is exactly one
>   island (i.e., one or more connected land cells).
>
> The island doesn't have "lakes" (water inside that isn't connected to
>   the water around the island). One cell is a square with side length 1.
>   The grid is rectangular, width and height don't exceed 100. Determine
>   the perimeter of the island.

Below is my solution. I haven't coded in Java since college and I'm trying to pick it up again. How is my style and is there any new Java features I can apply to the method to make it more concise? Thank you in advance!

Code:

```
class Solution {
    private int m;
    private int n;

    public int islandPerimeter(int[][] grid) {
        m = grid.length;
        n = grid[0].length;
        int perimeter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (grid[i][j] == 1) {
                    perimeter += getPerimeter(i, j, grid);
                }
            }
        }
        return perimeter;
    }

    private int getPerimeter(int i, int j, int[][] grid) {
        int perimeter = 0;
        if (i == 0 || grid[i-1][j] == 0) {
            perimeter++;
        }
        if (j == 0 || grid[i][j-1] == 0) {
            perimeter++;
        }
        if (i == m-1 || grid[i+1][j] == 0) {
            perimeter++;
        }
        if (j == n-1 || grid[i][j+1] == 0) {
            perimeter++;
        }
        return perimeter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of looking for cool new features of Java i would strongly suggest that you concentrate on the basics of Java: Objects:

### Think in Objects:

So far you have identified these Objects: `Map`, a `Cell` and an `Island` - so make some Objects of that type.

```
Map map = new Map(int[][] src);
Island island = map.extractIsland();
int diameter = island.getPerimater();
```

the `Map` needs some methods to properly extract the island

```
Cell cell = getCellAt(int x, int y);
```

and a method to gain relationship between each `Cells` on the map:

```
List<Cell> getNeighbours(Cell center);
```

and some elementary methods on the `Cell` class

```
boolean isWater();
boolean isLand();
int getAmountCoasts();
```

if you would have these elementary Objects you can simply create readable Code - see this example:

```
Cell center; //yes, here center.isLand() = true
List<Cell> neigbour = map.getNeighbours(center);
for (Cell neigbour: neigbours){
    if (neigbour.isWater()){
        center.addCoast();
    }
}
```

### once you are here you can use features from java 8

```
List<Cell> landCells = cells.stream.filter(Cell::isLand).collect(CollectorsToList());
int perimeter = landCells.stream.mapToInt(Cell::.getAmountCoasts).sum();
```

Hint: you better let the `Island` class handle that, see first hints - Responsibility for coastLine is within the `Island` class!)

### NOTE:

it's hard to think in objects whenever you try minimal code snippets as suggested from leet code. if minimal code is required, look maybe you are interested at [CodeGolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)...

Answer (score 1):

Storing properties of `grid`, which is a method parameter, into instance fields m and n, is bad practise. Now the reader has to wonder why their scope is exposed outside the method. M and n should stay in the same scope (they should be method variables).

`M` and `n` are bad names for `width` and `height`. There's nothing wrong with width and height and these would communicate their intended purpose immediately.

While `i` and `j` are common loop index variables, `x` and `y` are more commonly used for indexing a two dimensional grid. Some people use `row` and `col`, which are fine too.

While scanning every element is clean and works well for small input, you could just find the first element that has a "coastline" and check it's neighbors, ignoring all elements that don't have a "coastline". Follow the coastline clockwise and stop once you reach the first element again.